# BackboneJS testing collection fetch

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, sinon

I'm trying to test a Backbone collection's fetch. I'm using Sinon's fake server to set up a fake REST endpoint. The problem is that it seems like the request isn't sending.

I'm using Jasmine with Karma and running it through PhantomJS.

The problem is that the request is apparently not being sent. There aren't any errors but nothing is being logged to the console.

Here's the code:

```
describe("The Posts collection", function() {
  var posts;
  var server;

  beforeEach(function() {
    server = sinon.fakeServer.create();

    posts = new PostCollection();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    server.restore();
  });

  it("should fetch the posts from the api", function() {
     server.respondWith("GET", "/posts",
    [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    '{ "stuff": "is", "awesome": "in here" }']); 

    posts.fetch({
      success: function(model, response, options) {
        console.log("REQUEST SENT");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So as it turns out, I didn't read the docs carefully enough. With the fake server, you need to tell it to respond. I added the following after the call to `posts.fetch()`:

```
server.respond();
```

It works perfectly now.